# Альтернатива ADM

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем привет, столкнулся с [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197299/java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-clicking-on-android-device-monitor) проблемой. Вопрос: Есть ли альтернатива Android Device Monitor ? Мне нужно скопировать файл с девайса. У меня в виртуальном девайсе (genymotion) сохраняется база данных, мне ее нужно скопировать на локальный диск и открыть. Как это можно организовать? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

ADB из коммандной строки умеет это
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#copyfiles